Who were the watchmen? - Micah 7:4
Micah 7:4

The best of them is like a thorn bush, The most upright like a thorn
hedge. The day when you post your watchmen, Your punishment is coming.
Then their confusion will occur.

Question:

Who were the watchmen referred to here?
Why is it that when they post the watchmen their punishment is coming?


Actually, technically, the word about which the OP asks is not a noun, "watchmen", but a participle and must be translated as something like, "watching".  Thus, I would translate Micah 7:4 as:

[The] best [is like a] brier, upright as a thorn hedge;
[The] day of watching and your punishment comes
Now will be their confusion

The "watching" has been understood in two valid senses:

the watching of the prophets who predicted this punishment on the sinful nation
the watching of the watchmen on the walls of the city that warn of approaching enemies - the due punishment of their sin

The sense of the Hebrew appears to combine both meanings - all that has been predicted is coming and the looks outs can see it approaching.

Oh you're right, it's not a noun! That's odd. The major translations like (NASB, ESV, KJV, NKJV, NIV) they all use "your watchman" as if it's a noun. I don't understand why they would all take this approach?

@Jason_ - well it is a kind of noun being a participle or verbal-noun; hence my translation, "watching".  However, "watchmen" is a step too far.

+1. I'd certainly like to dig more into this. As always, thank you for your insights.
